# JavaScript random order functions

Tags: javascript, random

I have the following problem:

I want to call my functions `func1()`, `func2()` & `func3()` in a random order.
But i want to be sure that **every** function is called!

**If it's possible it also would be nice that no functions are used; just a random order of code sequences.**
Like this:

```
function xy(){

   //Call this sequence first second or third
   doSomething1

   //Call this sequence first second or third
   doSomething2

   //Call this sequence first second or third
   doSomething3

   //!! But call each sequence !!

}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: @NinaScholz random order call?

Comment: it depends of the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) for shuffling the functions and then call them via [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var a = function () { alert('a'); },
    b = function () { alert('b'); },
    c = function () { alert('c'); },
    array = [a, b, c];

array = array.map(function (a, i, o) {
    var j = (Math.random() * (o.length - i) | 0) + i,
        t = o[j];
    o[j] = a;
    return t;
});

array.forEach(function (a) { a(); });
```

Answer (score 3):

You could put all function names as strings into an Array, then sort this array randomly and call the functions:

```
var funcArr = new Array("func1", "func2", "func3");
shuffle(funcArr); //You would need a shuffle function for that. Can be easily found on the internet.

for (var i = 0; i < funcArr.length; i++)
    window[funcArr[i]]();
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want functions but lines of code to be sorted randomly, then that's not going to work. JavaScript does not have a `goto` command (at least not without an external API), so you can't jump between code lines. You can only mix functions, as shown above.

Comment: Do you think there is possiblity to do this without external functions, just with code sequences? --> 3 sequences called in random order.

Comment: What do you mean by external functions? The `shuffle` method? And does that exclude functions like `Math.random()` as well? Because otherwise there is no possibility.

Comment: I have `code seq1`, `code seq2`, ... and want to call them in a random order

Comment: Yeah, but what do you mean by `external functions`? That idea requires some kind of randomness, and randomness can only be created by using functions such as `Math.random()`.

Comment: I dont want to do `function xy(){...}`, i want to randomise the sequences in a function

Comment: So for example you want to have something like this: `var x = 0; function xy() { x = 1; x = 2; var y = x * 2; }` and then want the lines in the function to be sorted randomly? So the result of y can be `0` (when it's called first), `2` when it's called after the first line and `4` when everything is in order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97092/discussion-between-sese-schneider-and-tobias-baumeister).

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to do that, one of the most easy way is like this:

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function () {
  this.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
}

[func1, func2, func3].shuffle().forEach(function(func, index, array){
  func();
});
```