# How to run a group of functions in a random order

Tags: javascript, html, function, math, random

I want to run 4 functions in a random order. Not sure where to start. Here is my code without the random order.

```
generate.addEventListener('click', generateclick)

function generateclick(){
fifth()
fourth()
majthird()
minthird()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111676/javascript-random-order-functions

Answer (score -2):

```js
function getRandomIntFromArr(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

const funMap = {
  1: () => {
    console.log("1 fun called");
  },
  2: () => {
    console.log("2 fun called");
  },
  3: () => {
    console.log("3 fun called");
  },
  4: () => {
    console.log("4 fun called");
  },
};

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let j = getRandomIntFromArr(array);
  funMap[`${j}`]();
  array = array.filter((el) => el !== j);
}
```